# Datagridview component does not implement row separation in xamarin forms using visual studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin, gridview, visual-studio-2019

Good evening fellow Xamaritans, I am doing a final year project using visual studio 2019 and I need to give a space to the elements within a listview that in turn contains a gridview to better organize its content, which is a list of departments, but when I load it, they come out very close together, I set the rowspacing property of the grid to 10 and nothing separates the elements, I send you an image for a better understanding

example :-

[image]

```
I have tried to automatically change the height of the rows, but I still do not obtain positive results, I send you my code in xaml where the code in question is implemented



<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                 
                            Grid.Row="3"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  
                                 >
                        <ListView x:Name="lstdepartamentos" 
                                      IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleDepartamentos}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ListaDepartamentos}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding DepSeleccionado}" 
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" 
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" 
                                      SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                                      
                                      >
                            
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <Grid RowSpacing="10"
                                              RowDefinitions="*"
                                              >
                                            
                                            <control:RoundedLabel Text="{Binding DescripcionDep}" 
                                                                  TextColor="WhiteSmoke"
                                                                  FontSize="15"
                                                                  FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                                                  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                                  VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                                 
                                                      
                                                            />
                                        </Grid>

                                            


                                       
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                        <ListView x:Name="lstarticulos"
                                      IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleArticulos,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ListaArticulos}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding ArtSeleccionado}"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" 
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" >
                            
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <Grid RowSpacing="10"
                                              RowDefinitions="0.33*"
                                              >
                                            
                                            <control:RoundedLabelWhite Text="{Binding DescripcionArt}" 
                                                           TextColor="Black"
                                                           FontSize="15"
                                                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                           Grid.Row="0" 
                                                           Grid.Column="0"                                                          
                                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"            
                                                                       />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: The Grid serves no purpose here.  Try adding a top/bottom margin to your label instead